# C updating string incrementally

Tags: c, pointers, heap-memory, c-strings, function-definition

I am trying to update string step by step in C. The code i tried is below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int writech(char **text, char ch) {
    **text = ch;

    return 1;
}

char *write(int array[], size_t size) {
    char *string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(size+1));
    int i, n;

    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        n = writech(&string, '0' + array[i]);
        string += n;
    }

    return string;
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    char *str = write(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));

    printf("%s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Here, `write` function should update `string` by calling other function and return updated `string` at the end. The code compiled and run successfully, though `str` (at the end of `main`) is empty after all. Actually, my task is to create string that contain table of some data and return it at the end. Pseudo code for my idea is below:

```
char *render_table() {
    char *table = malloc(sizeof table);

    write_header(table);
    write_row(table, some_data);
    write_row(table, some_data);
    write_footer(table)

    return table;
}
```

For implementing this pseudo code I wrote the above code, but not able to update passed string successfully. I know pointers are passed to function as copies, and passed memory of my string (`writech(&string`) to function, but `string` not updated still. What am i missing?

**P.S.** Tweaking with pointers is really struggling for me as beginner in C. What would you suggest?

Comment: The `return string;` in `write()` returns the value after the several additions, ie: it returns the end of the string. You need to keep a copy of the original beginning of the string and return that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string` is updated. The problem is the pointer `string` is updated and the information of the beginning of the string is lost. You have to hold the information.

One more point is that terminating null-character must be added to pass the buffer for `%s` (without specifying length to print).

Also note that casting results of `malloc()` in C is [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Try this:

```
char *write(int array[], size_t size) {
    char *string = malloc(sizeof(char)*(size+1));
    char *cursor = string;
    int i, n;

    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        n = writech(&cursor, '0' + array[i]);
        cursor += n;
    }
    writech(&cursor, '\0');

    return string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for solution. With this approach, where I should free memory allocated to cursor and string?

Comment: @ElginCahangirov For `cursor` there is nothing to free. The string shall be freed in `main` after the `printf`, i.e. `free(str);`

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you are making this much more complicated than needed.

Simply do:

```
for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    string[i] = '0' + array[i]);
}
string[i] = '\0';
```

If for some reason you really want to use the `writech` function, you can change it to:

```
void writech(char *text, char ch) {
    *text = ch;
}
```

and call it like:

```
for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    writech(string + i, '0' + array[i]);
}
string[i] = '\0';
```

but it's really just making a simple task complex.

**EDIT due to comment**

If you (in your real code) don't know how many chars will be added by a function call, you simply do:

```
int writeSomethingA(char* str, ... other arguments ...)
{
    // update str, e.g. like str[0] = 'a'; str[1] = 'b';
    //                  or strcpy(str, "Some text");

    return NumberOfCharAdded;
}
```

(make similar B and C versions)

and call them like:

```
char* string malloc(....);
int idx = 0;

idx += writeSomethingA(string + idx, ... other arguments ...);

idx += writeSomethingB(string + idx, ... other arguments ...);

idx += writeSomethingC(string + idx, ... other arguments ...);

string[idx] = '\0';
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion. But your solution doesn't appeal my objective, since I don't know beforehand how many characters will be written. For loop in the code is just for representation for my real problem. See pseudo code for the real task.

Comment: @ElginCahangirov What do you mean by: " I don't know beforehand how many characters will be written." ? The size is passed to the function

Comment: For example, write_header(table); function like this may write different number of characters based on some style or other conditions. That's way, I return `int` at the end of writech function and then use this int to increment pointer.

Comment: yeah it is good idea to pass incremented pointer to function. But I think solution suggested above is neater. Thanks for your effors!

Comment: @ElginCahangirov No problem - you are free to select the answer you prefer. Let me just recommend that you do **not** pass `&cursor`. There is no reason to pass it by address and it's making your code confusing and it hurts performance. Just pass `cursor` - it's sifficient for adding to the string.

Answer (score 0):

For starters it is unclear why the function `writech`

```
int writech(char **text, char ch) {
    **text = ch;

    return 1;
}
```

has the first parameter with the type `char **` instead of `char *`.

The function can be defined like

```
int writech( char *text, char ch ) {
    *text = ch;
    return 1;
}
```

Within the function `write` the pointer `string` is being changed in the for loop. So the function returns a pointer that does not point to the beginning of the allocated memory.

Also as you are using the conversion specifier %s to output the character array in main then the array shall contain a string. That is the array shall have contain the terminating zero character `'\0'`.

The function can be implemented the following way

```
char * write( const int array[], size_t size ) {
    char *string = malloc( size + 1 );

    if ( string != NULL )
    {
        char *p = string;

        while ( size-- ) {
            p +=  writech( p, '0' + *array++ );
        }

        *p = '\0';
    }

    return string;
}
```

And you should free the allocated memory before exiting main like

```
free( str );
```